# Facebook: The parameter app_id is required after pressing share button

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I have this code that works fine for `BLOGGER`, but now I am getting this error:

> "The parameter app_id is required"

I have tried many methods to add `app_id` but I haven't found one that worked.

```
    <!-- FACEBOOK VIRAL SCRIPT BEGIN -->   

<style>
    #fvsbg {
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        z-index: 99;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    } 
    #fvsmain {
        position:fixed;
        top:200px;
        left:50%;
        margin-left:-225px;
        z-index:100;
        width:450px;
        color:#333;
        text-align:center;
        font-family:arial,sans-serif;
        font-size:13px;
        background:transparent;
        line-height:1;
        height:200px;
        display:none;
    }
    #sharebtn {
        width: 200px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }
    #h1 {
        color: #FFFFFF;   
        font-size: 2em;
        margin: 0.67em 0;
        text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em black
    }       
    @media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {             
        #fvsmain {
            position:fixed;
            top:0;
        }
    }

</style>
<div id="fb-root"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        // SETTINGS (put information inside "")
        // See this screenshot to understand separate parts: http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/7468/hnk2.png

        var AppID = '368706166616499'; // your Facebook App ID
        var link = 'http://biebergotpunched.blogspot.com/'; // link to your blog (must be the same as app's domain)
        var title = 'bbbb'; // title of the post
        var description = 'bbbb'; //description of the post
        var picture = ''; //image link for post

        // --------


    // FACEBOOK API     

      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        // init the FB JS SDK
        FB.init({
          appId      : '368706166616499',
          appId: AppID
        });

        // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
      };

      // Load the SDK asynchronously
      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    function feed(){
        FB.ui(
          {
            method: 'share',
            name: title,
            link: link,
            picture: picture,
            description: description
          },
          function(response) {
            if (response.post_id) {
                SetCookie("FVSC","TRUE",1);
                document.getElementById("fvsbg").style.display="none";
                document.getElementById("fvsmain").style.display="none";
            } else {
              alert('You must share this to unlock the page!');
            }
          }
        );
    }

    // FB API END



    function SetCookie(cookieName,cookieValue,nDays) {
     var today = new Date();
     var expire = new Date();
     if (nDays==null || nDays==0) nDays=1;
     expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*nDays);
     document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue)
                     + ";expires="+expire.toGMTString();
    }

    function ReadCookie(cookieName) {
     var theCookie=" "+document.cookie;
     var ind=theCookie.indexOf(" "+cookieName+"=");
     if (ind==-1) ind=theCookie.indexOf(";"+cookieName+"=");
     if (ind==-1 || cookieName=="") return "";
     var ind1=theCookie.indexOf(";",ind+1);
     if (ind1==-1) ind1=theCookie.length; 
     return unescape(theCookie.substring(ind+cookieName.length+2,ind1));
    }       

    window.onload=function() {
        if(ReadCookie("FVSC") == "TRUE")
        {
            document.getElementById("fvsbg").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("fvsmain").style.display="none";
        }
        if(ReadCookie("FVSC") != "TRUE")
        {
            document.getElementById("fvsbg").style.backgroundColor="rgba(0,0,0,0.6)";
            document.getElementById("fvsmain").style.display="block";
        }
    };      

    if(document.URL.indexOf("blogspot") >= 0)
    {
        if(document.URL.split('.')[1] + document.URL.split('.')[2] + document.URL.split('.')[3] != 'blogspotcom/undefined')
        {
            window.location = link + "/ncr";
        }
    }           
    </script>

    <div id="fvsbg"></div>
    <div id="fvsmain">
        <h1 id="h1" class="center">Share to Unlock this page</h1>
        <a href="#" onclick="feed();"><img id="sharebtn" src="http://i.imgur.com/5mSP6c1.png" /></a>
    </div>  

<!-- FACEBOOK VIRAL SCRIPT END -->
```

Comment: Recommend reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve